# Jquery load content with ssl

Tags: jquery, ssl, load

i'm new to Jquery.

When i use Jquery to load a content, it's like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>load demo</title>
<style>
body {
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Arial;
}
</style>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="live"></div>
<script>
$( "#live" ).load( "livescore.php" );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Every thing ok, but when i upload to my hosting and run with ssl (https:), it doen't load?

I tried in local, it's running ok, but have problem when run with secure domain.

Thank for the help!

Comment: What do you see in your console? Any errors?

Comment: No error, it's show a blank page.

Comment: I meant in the console. Rather than focus on the *content*, what does the *request* do? Return a 200 OK? Any headers? What's the fully qualified URI?